# Fetch API blocked, but not AJAX or XHR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I've made an API call to a URL shortener, using the exact code provided by the source. Fetch returns a 400 error (Bad request), but JQuery and XHR both return the shortened URL without any issues. Why is that?

I've tried adding `mode: 'no-cors'` as well as `"crossDomain": true` to the request, but neither work.

[→ Image of What each request returns here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBKn2.png)

Here's my code:

(FETCH)

```
fetch("https://url-shortener-service.p.rapidapi.com/shorten", {
"method": "POST",
"headers": {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "url-shortener-service.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
},
"body": {
    "url": "https://google.com/"
}
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

(XHR)

```
var data = "url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://url-shortener-service.p.rapidapi.com/shorten");
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "url-shortener-service.p.rapidapi.com");
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.send(data);
```

(JQuery)

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://url-shortener-service.p.rapidapi.com/shorten",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "url-shortener-service.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY",
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "data": {
        "url": "https://google.com/"
    }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `credentials: 'include'` ?

Comment: Have a look at the request headers and parameters in the chrome console, to find out differences between calls

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I'll try those and get back you :)

Comment: @Noob `credentials: 'include'` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Is the server/service relying on cookies? I've found that `fetch` API *won't* send/receive cookies by *default* => [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Thanks @Gruber. I'll check it out and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to stringify the body something like this

```
body: JSON.stringify({ url: "https://google.com/" }),
```

So the entire code will look like this

```
fetch("https://url-shortener-service.p.rapidapi.com/shorten", {
"method": "POST",
"headers": {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "url-shortener-service.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
},
body: JSON.stringify({ url: "https://google.com/" }),

})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Pratham! It seems you were half right. What I did to make it work was to do what you said—`JSON.stringify()` the `body` object. Then I changed the `content-type` to `application/json`. Finally, I added another `.then()` block. The first one converted the response with the fetch API's `response.json()` and the second one `console.logs` the data. See an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Ludolfyn/shmfrxo6/. If you want to update your answer with those changes then I'm more than happy to mark your answer as the solve :)